# asp.net c# make the web service get not post

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have build this class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace TestCanvas
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for WebService1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }
}
```

and the web serivce hello world works just by post not by get.

why please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look your webconfig configuration. You need to add the HttpGet protocol to work with GET.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <webServices>
            <protocols>
                <add name="HttpGet"/>
            </protocols>
        </webServices>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```